# Understanding persistence in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, caching, rdd

I am fairly new to Spark, and was playing around it a bit and have a few doubts regarding it:-

Here is the code that I am trying out:-

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;

/**
 * Computes an approximation to pi
 * Usage: JavaSparkPi [slices]
 */
public final class JavaSparkPi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkPi").setMaster("local[4]");


        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        JavaRDD<String> data = jsc.textFile("/Users/sanchay/Desktop/2017-08-08");


        while(true) {

            Thread.sleep(1000);

                    int count = data.map(s -> s.length()).reduce((a, b) -> (a + b));
            System.out.println("count == " + count);

        }

      //  jsc.stop();

    }
}
```

1) Since I am currently running in the local mode, upon each iteration the time taken is getting reduced (file size is around 150 Mb). This would be because each time the RDD is getting cached. I wanted to know when I would be running this on a cluster of remote nodes, will I experience this same behaviour, because it is not necessary that the same node will get the same partition it computed before.

2) Also,I tried to **un-persist** the 'data' variable above, however, I noted no difference in the time taken, as in the time reduced from the 1st iteration to the 2nd, implying something somewhere was cached . So, is it still somehow getting cached, or am I missing something obvious here.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with persistence in Spark. That would happen if you call rdd.cache() or rdd.persist(), inside a single Spark app (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence). A Spark application run has no interaction with another run whatsoever. 
What do you mean by "I tried to un-persist the 'data' " ?

Comment: I have a doubt here. When the loop runs for the second time, the 'data' variable, does it read the file again, or picks from the cache?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood, my bad. I thought you meant you ran the whole application a second time. You can see what Spark is doing under the hood in the Spark UI : you will see the "DAG" and the jobs/tasks/stages. It might help you!

Comment: @Sanchay In spark point of view, it will read file again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO it won't `persist()` by default we have to mention which `RDD` to be persisted without the external method spark won't persist anything

you can persist an RDD like

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel 

val source = s.map(rec => (rec.split(",")(0), rec)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
 //DISK_ONLY,MEMORY_AND_DISK,MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER etc
```

Default caching will take place in memory for that we can give that as `val rdd1 = a.cache()`

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty clear now. Resonates with the documentation as well:- https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence.      Would upvote once I get enough reputation.:p

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Hey Vignesh, I had a minor doubt. If I had JavaRDD<String> data2 = jsc.textFile("/Users/sanchay/Desktop/2017-08-08"); JavaRDD<Integer> countRDD = data2.map(s->s.length());   then every time countRDD is accessed in the code, it will open the file again, is this correct? And if I cache countRDD, then it gets picked up from the cache?

Comment: `data2.map` is a trasformation it will access the file only when it an action like `collect, save, take, etc`. Yes if you are accessing coundRDD often without persisting it it will go read the file for every access, better persist in memory if the data is small.

Answer (score 2):

I think it become faster on later iteration because of OS caching mechanism. Briefly, when you read file, the filesystem module will put its content in some memory location to make faster access next time. You don't cache RDD explicitly so it's not in memory, each run it first read content file again then do map, reduce ops..., but the file content is in somewhere that's fast to access so the later run will get speedup.